# check if result exists inside of 3 arrays of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

3 arrays of hashes `likes(@contest)["data"], shares(@contest)["data"], comments(@contest)["data"]` with this structure:

**likes(@contest)["data"**]

```
{"id"=>"101530244445809095", "name"=>"Jhon"}
{"id"=>"777860702747597", "name"=>"Pepe"}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

**shares(@contest)["data"**]

```
{"id"=>"101530244445809095", "name"=>"Andres"}
{"id"=>"777860702747597", "name"=>"Pepe"}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

**comments(@contest)["data"**]

```
{"id"=>"101530244445809095", "name"=>"Paul"}
{"id"=>"777860702747597", "name"=>"Pepe"}
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I want to get as a result, only, the common hash or hashes, in the three, in this case

```
{"id"=>"777860702747597", "name"=>"Pepe"}
```

Comment: I would like to offer a few suggestions for creating example input and output (which is generally very helpful to the reader): 1) the input should be a (valid) Ruby object; 2) set the input equal to a variable; 3) simplify the example as much as possible; and 4) cover all the cases.

Comment: Re 1: to have a valid Ruby object you need to express each of the three arrays (with no `...`s) as proper arrays; e.g., `[{"id"=>"101530244445809095", "name"=>"Jhon"}]`. ``likes(@contest)["data"]` is neither "stand-alone" nor necessary.

Comment: Re 2: Set `a1 = [{"id"=>"101530244445809095", "name"=>"Jhon"}]` and similar for the other arrays. Alternatively, as I've done in my answer, use just one variable for an array of arrays of hashes. That way, those giving answers can simply refer to those variables, without having to define them again.

Comment: Re 3: There's no need for the value of `"id"` to be such a long string. If you shorten it (to, say, ``{"id"=>"101", "name"=>"Jhon"}`) it's easier for the reader to spot differences and the example is no less useful. I'm forever seeing examples with hashes containing many, many key-value pairs, with long keys and values, where just a couple is all that's needed.

Comment: Re 4: You should broaden your example to include at least one hash that is not present in all the arrays.

Comment: Consider editing your question to incorporate these suggestions (except #2), in part because your question may be read by many others in future. That should also avoid additional downvotes. If you do, include "Edit:...", so you do not render any answers or comments nonsensical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the elements of `a` are your arrays of hashes:

```
a = [[{ "id"=>"101", "name"=>"Jhon"   },
      { "id"=>"777", "name"=>"Pepe"   },
      { "id"=>"123", "name"=>"Zelda"  }],
     [{ "id"=>"101", "name"=>"Andres" },
      { "id"=>"777", "name"=>"Pepe"   },
      { "id"=>"123", "name"=>"Zelda"  }],
     [{ "id"=>"101", "name"=>"Paul"   },
      { "id"=>"777", "name"=>"Pepe"   }]]
    ]
```

the hashes that appear in all arrays are:

```
a.reduce(:&)
  #=> [{"id"=>"777860", "name"=>"Pepe"}]
```

This of course works with any numbers of arrays and hashes.

See the docs for [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) to see what's going on. You'll see that the method has four forms. It's the second one that I'm using here (as used by @Helder and suggested by @Arup). It gives the same result as:

```
a.reduce(&:&)
  #=> [{"id"=>"777860", "name"=>"Pepe"}]
```

which is shorthand for:

```
a.reduce { |common, arr| common & arr }
```

Comment: I liked the previous revision with simpler looking hashes

Comment: @hyperrjas Please next time on wards put some efforts on your questions before presenting it.. :) It will help us.

Comment: @cary make it _tight_ `a.reduce(:&)` ,,, :D :D

Comment: Yeah! now, let's other figure out what is going on.. ;)

Comment: @Wand (aka "conehead"), I changed the example so that it would tie in with the comments I left on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&` to calculate the intersection, which will give the hashes that are in common in the 3 arrays:

```
[likes(@contest)["data"], shares(@contest)["data"], comments(@contest)["data"]]
.inject(:&)
```

Comment: I just noticed your answer. Good one! I borrowed `(:&)`.